# Authentication error when roaming from one AP to another

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a LAN with two APs to access it from different locations. Both APs are configured to have same network name and password.

From time to time, when some clients roam from one AP to another, they get "authentication error". This can last for some minutes, then disappear. At the moment of error, network is not working actually, while wireless signal is reported of high strength.

Also, I can disconnect and reconnect back to fix error.

How to ensure smooth roaming?

One AP is D-Link DIR-615 in AP mode, and security is configured as follows:

[image]

another AP is DrayTek Vigor 2920Vn and is configured as follows:

[image]

Are there any differences in configuration here, which can cause described error?

**UPDATE**

Another options for `Mode` on DrayTek:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your DrayTek Vigor 2920Vn has both TKIP and AES enabled. This requires your clients to use AES for unicast packets (the vast majority of the packets they send) but requires them to use TKIP for multicast and broadcast packets.

Your D-Link DIR-615 is in a more secure, more compatible mode. Its set to only use AES for unicasts as well as multicasts and broadcasts.

When your clients roam from the D-Link to the DrayTek, they're having to downgrade the encryption cipher they use on their multicasts and broadcasts, and my guess is that's what they're choking on.

Comment: From my point of view the text implies, that AES is used, since mode is set strightly to `WPA2`. There is an option `Mixed WPA + WPA2`, which would mean TKIP is used sometimes.

Comment: See my update pls

Comment: @Dims Perhaps, but what a terrible UI if it still says "TKIP for WPA…" after you've selected what ought to be WPA2 (AES) - only. Using Wireshark or another packet capture tool in 802.11 monitor mode would allow you to capture a beacon or probe request, which would clear this up authoritatively.

Comment: Yes, DrayTek has extremely weird UI.

Answer (score 0):

it may be not security issue 
just be sure of the next 
1- the pattern of the two access point interference not exceed 15% , which is Cisco recommendation to grantee safe handover from access point to another, and this must be done by site survey 
2- those two access point acting as wireless hub so simple the mac address table of the hosting switch could have the same mac address from two different source ports which is simple  "LOOP" so you must found some way for loop privation such as configuring spanning tree protocol "STP" OR rapid spanning tree protocol "RSTP"

Comment: This does not really answer the proposed question.